# Copy bootloader/boot partition to another disk (cdm-crypt)

Tags: debian, usb, dm-crypt

I installed Debian jesse on an USB stick. I have like usual in these cases 4 partitions. Boot, root, swap, home. Last 3 of course encrypted.

But during installation, I don't know why, Debian didn't ask to me where to install the boot loader (grub).

Debian automatically installed the boot loader on the mbr of my main hdd's pc.

So now, I have an almost full encrypted USB that only works on that specific pc. The USB key by itself can't boot.

How can I fix this? I think I must somehow copy the mbr content in the boot partition on my USB. But I don't have technical knowledge about it.

I can't understand why Debian didn't ask me where to install grub.

I did a manual install via the standard Debian wizard install.

Debian works great however I would like to have the chance to use this USB key in any pc I have.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command [`grub-install`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html) to install the first stage of Grub, i.e. the bit that is loaded by the BIOS. For example, if your USB stick is currently connected as `/dev/sdb`, run the following command as root:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```